# SQL UNION strange error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

Im developing a Lottery application, and I want to check if any of the numbers on the users tickets match any balls that have been drawn, 2 points for each match. So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT firstName, SUM(points) AS totalPoints FROM (
(SELECT userID, firstName, 2 * COUNT(*) AS points
FROM DRAWS NATURAL JOIN TICKETS NATURAL JOIN USERS
WHERE
    number1 = ball1 OR
    number1 = ball2 OR
    number1 = ball3 OR
    number1 = ball4
GROUP BY userID, drawID) AS N1
UNION ALL
(SELECT userID, firstName, 2 * COUNT(*) AS points
FROM DRAWS NATURAL JOIN TICKETS NATURAL JOIN USERS
WHERE
    number2 = ball1 OR
    number2 = ball2 OR
    number2 = ball3 OR
    number2 = ball4
GROUP BY userID, drawID) AS N2
UNION ALL
(SELECT userID, firstName, 2 * COUNT(*) AS points
FROM DRAWS NATURAL JOIN TICKETS NATURAL JOIN USERS
WHERE
    number3 = ball1 OR
    number3 = ball2 OR
    number3 = ball3 OR
    number3 = ball4
GROUP BY userID, drawID) AS N3 ) AS TOT
GROUP BY userID;
```

MySQL said: Documentation
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS N2
UNION ALL
(SELECT userID, firstName, 2 * COUNT(*) AS points
FROM DRA' at line 18

The structure for the tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
firstName CHAR(16),
lastName CHAR(16),
email CHAR(32) UNIQUE,
phone CHAR(16),
userName CHAR(20),
passWord CHAR(20),
balance INTEGER );

CREATE TABLE TICKETS (
ticketID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
userID INTEGER,
drawID INTEGER,
date DATE,
number1 INTEGER,
number2 INTEGER,
number3 INTEGER,
score INTEGER,
prize INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE DRAWS (
drawID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
dateOpen DATE,
dateClose DATE,
gameID INTEGER,
ball1 INTEGER,
ball2 INTEGER,
ball3 INTEGER,
ball4 INTEGER,
bonusBall INTEGER,
dateDrawn DATE,
profit INTEGER, 
charityID INTEGER );
```

I think its a problem with my UNION, because the individual queries work fine. I have been trying to sort this out for a while and I can't do it so I thought I would ask the professionals. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses & the aliases, since `UNION ALL`, unlike join's, combine the result from multiple `SELECT` statements into a single result set:

```
SELECT firstName, SUM(points) AS totalPoints FROM
(SELECT userID, firstName, 2 * COUNT(*) AS points
FROM DRAWS NATURAL JOIN TICKETS NATURAL JOIN USERS
WHERE
    number1 = ball1 OR
...
GROUP BY userID, drawID
UNION ALL
SELECT userID, firstName, 2 * COUNT(*) AS points
FROM DRAWS NATURAL JOIN TICKETS NATURAL JOIN USERS
WHERE
    number2
...
) AS Tot
```